# php função outra página

Tags: php, funções

Isso é um código em outra página php tento chamar as funções mas dão erro como se a variavel não existisse , alguem tem alguma ideia?

```
<?php
$host = "host";
$port = 587;
$username= 'usuario';
$password = 'senha';
$secure = 'tls';
$from = 'from@.com.br';

function host()
{

    return $host;
}
function port()
{
    return $port;
}
function user()
{
    return $username;
}
function secure()
{
    return $secure;
}
function password()
{
    return $password;
}
function from()
{
    return $from;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tente assim:

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['host'] = "host";
$GLOBALS['port'] = 587;
$GLOBALS['username'] = 'usuario';
$GLOBALS['password'] = 'senha';
$GLOBALS['secure'] = 'tls';
$GLOBALS['from'] = 'from@.com.br';

function host()
{

    return $GLOBALS['host'];
}
function port()
{
    return $GLOBALS['port'];
}
function user()
{
    return $GLOBALS['username'];
}
function secure()
{
    return $GLOBALS['secure'];
}
function password()
{
    return $GLOBALS['password'];
}
function from()
{
    return $GLOBALS['from'];
}
```

Comment: valeuzao!!!!!!!